# Creating default Userstorie or Tasks on creating a new iteration (TFS2013)

Tags: tfs, iteration, tfs-workitem

We work with TFS 2013 and every month we create a new iteration (vx.x.x.x etc). Every iteration has a standard set of Userstory's / tasks that need to be done to complete the iteration. Currently we need to create these workitems every month with the same data in them. Is there a way to automate this process? I was thinking about "Default work items" for an iteration, is that possible in TFS 2013?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it without writing some code. I suggest using TFS API and create some kind of tool which will create new iteration and required work items. E.g.

```
var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("collection url, e.g. http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
var css = tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();
var store = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var server = tpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();
var project = store.Projects["MyProject"];

/*get root iteration node*/
NodeInfo rootIteration = css.ListStructures(project.Uri.ToString()).First(n => n.StructureType == "ProjectLifecycle");

/*create new iteration*/
css.CreateNode("TestIteration", rootIteration.Uri.ToString());

/*sync changes*/
server.SyncExternalStructures(WorkItemServer.NewRequestId(), project.Uri.ToString());
project.Store.RefreshCache();

/*create new bug in the new iteration*/
var bug = project.WorkItemTypes["Bug"].NewWorkItem();
bug.Title = "Test";
bug.AreaPath = "MyProject\\TestIteration";
bug.Save();
```

Comment: I'm currently using Excel to copy the work items and paste them into a new Query for the next iteration. That works fine aswell. I was hoping there was an easier (more automatic) way to do this. Sadly there isn't. Thanks for the reply though.